# flutter webapp is not working but iOS and Apk files are working

Tags: flutter, flutter-web

Developing a single webapp with http package
iOS and apk files are working fine, but webapp is not updating content .. Image is attached below

```
Future<Exercise> fetchSensorValues() async {

    final _sensorAPIurl = 'my_url';

    var response =  await http.get(Uri.parse(_sensorAPIurl));

    if(response.statusCode == 200){

      print(response.body);

      final exercise = exerciseFromJson(response.body);


      return exercise ;
    }else {

      print("EROOR") ;

      throw Exception('Failed to load data');

    }
  }

``[sample image][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/GbB2p.jpg
```

Comment: Are you getting any error message? Likely a CORS issue if you're requesting data from another server.

Comment: No error is showing

Comment: So what's stored in `response` after you've called `get()`? If it's not an error check if the body actually contains the data you're expecting

Comment: Thanks for your help .. It was actually CORS issue as you suggested

Answer (score 0):

In Web app you need to load https content in order to work.
Make sure you are getting content in https and not in http.

Comment: Yes I'm using a https link